# npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration

Tags: firebase, npm

I am stuck at this for long, checked several post but no solution. I am trying to deploy firebase functions.

I have run, npm install -g firebase-tools, npm firebase login, firebase init functions, and when i get to npm install i see this issue with python on terminal

```
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Osas Divine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Osas Divine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Osas Divine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Osas Divine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
```

I have removed python from my pc, all i simply want is to deploy firebase but these errors are confusing and no progress, i dont need python how do i stop terminal from running it

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^0.4.0",
    "sharp": "^0.18.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Install python for windows simply by typing `python` on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

The error reported is due to missing or unavailable `python` installation for your OS.

One the packages listed in your `package.json` file requires `python`, so you need to [install Python for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) and when you are ready you must make node aware of its existence by (***replace the file path** to your python installation, you can use python3 or what is required by the referenced node package*):

```sh
npm config set python D:\Library\Python\Python27\python.exe
```

Comment: I have added my package.json I just want to confirm that I really do need Python on my windows, than I will proceed with the answer provided.

Comment: Happens to be on Ubuntu when `python` and `python3` are both installed. NPM is too stupid to  figure it out.